# Trouble converting date with MomentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to convert a date using MomentJS:

```
console.log(moment(this.entities[i].created_at).isValid());
this.entities[i].created_at = moment(this.entities[i].created_at).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");
```

The console log returns `true`, and from my understanding, this means the date IS in a VALID format. However, I still get this error message:

```
value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments: 
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 21-05-2020 19:43, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
```

If I console.log the date, I receive `2020-05-21 19:43:58.099745+00`.

I've also tried these approaches but no success:

```
moment(this.entities[i].created_at.toString()).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");
```

```
moment(this.entities[i].created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss').format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");
```

```
moment(this.entities[i].created_at.toString(), 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss').format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Your input string (from `this.entities[i].created_at`) appears to be: `21-05-2020 19:43` (as captured by `_i`).

Thus, your input format needs to match.

```
moment(this.entities[i].created_at, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm")
```

If you intend to format it differently from there, you can:

```
moment(this.entities[i].created_at, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I'd like to keep the DD-MM-YYYY format, but it's weird that this works: `this.entities[i].created_at = moment(this.entities[i].created_at, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");` but this returns the error I posted in my original question: `this.entities[i].created_at = moment(this.entities[i].created_at, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm").format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");`
I'd also like to not show the seconds. Do you know why it's still showing the seconds even though I haven't specified they should appear?

Comment: Watch your data and formats closely.  The format specified in the first `moment` function is the *input* format, and must match the data that's being passed in.  That gives you a `Moment` object.  From there you can create a string with any format you like with the `format` function.  In other words:  `moment(inputString, inputFormat).format(outputFormat)`